# how to show loading image when a child node is loading data dynamically using JSTREE?

Tags: jquery, jstree

In my project, iam populating the child nodes data dynamically through ajax call.As data is more, it is taking time to load the data.So i want to show a loading image in the tree(in child node position). how to achieve this?

Comment: I have found the answer to this question.When a node is loading in JSTREE, it will be having "jstree-loading" class.

So in your CSS file, just add the below line.
 
.jstree-default a.jstree-loading .jstree-icon { background:url(image name) center center no-repeat !important; }

note:Image name is a variable.So do not forget to keep in in quotations.

Ex code: 

.jstree-default a.jstree-loading .jstree-icon { background:url("myImage.gif") center center no-repeat !important; }


Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a node is loading in JSTREE, it will be having `jstree-loading` class.

Therefore, just add the following to your CSS:

```
.jstree-default a.jstree-loading .jstree-icon { 
    background:url(image name) center center no-repeat !important; 
}
```

**Note:**

Image name is a variable.Do not forget to keep in in quotations.

Ex code:

```
.jstree-default a.jstree-loading .jstree-icon { 
    background:url("myImage.gif") center center no-repeat !important; 
}
```