# Add loading indicator when select node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jstree

I have many categories in my jstree and I want to add some info to user like  loading indicator while selecting node and thier children. I tried this way
[how to show loading image when a child node is loading data dynamically using JSTREE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491806/how-to-show-loading-image-when-a-child-node-is-loading-data-dynamically-using-js)
but It didn't work for me.

```
thisInstance.treeInstance.jstree({
            core: {
                data: values,
                themes: {
                    name: 'proton',
                    responsive: true
                }
            },
            plugins: plugins
        });
```

[image]

Any ideas?

When I select or unselect I want to get user loading indicator to know that some work is in progress

Comment: In order to understand what doesn't work, you need to show the code, the efforts you have put to solve it, and the point where you got stuck.

Comment: I added additional informations

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.
I would like to show loader when selecting node with many children.

"activate_node" function trigger event when finish but not when start.

I try to use click event : 
    // that.jsTree = $('#tree-view');

```
that.jsTree.on("click.jstree", ".jstree-anchor", function (e) {
    console.log("on click jstree"); // display
    that.jsTree.hide(); // test not work
});

that.jsTree.on('activate_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
     console.log("after activate_node"); // display
     that.jsTree.show(); // test not work
});
```